# Concatenate tagged PDF files using the older version iText 4.2.0

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am maintaining the code which is using older version iText 4.2. Now, I am trying to merging multiple tagged PDF files into one using following codes:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
document.open();
PdfReader reader;
int n;
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    reader = new PdfReader(files[i]);
    n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {
        copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
    }
    copy.freeReader(reader);
    reader.close();
}
document.close();
```

However, the tags are not copied over at all. since this is old version, I  cannot find the function getImportedPage(reader, ++page, true) with third boolean parameter.

My question is whether the version of itext is not possible to achieve this? I also want to let you know I cannot upgrade my itext version to newer ones.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have tried to copy.setTagged(). It doesn't help at all. The tag I try to merge is like: <</Type/StructElem
/S /H1
/P 33 0 R
/K [<</Type /MCR /Pg 6 0 R /MCID 37>>]
>>

Comment: iText 4.2 is not an official version. The people who published this version aren't on Stack Overflow, and don't care about the users of the fork they made. As for iText Group: we care about users of the official version. Unfortunately, we can't help people who are using a rogue version because we don't know what's inside that rogue version (and there's no incentive for us to look inside). This being said: merging Tagged PDFs, maintaining the Tagging was only supported in iText 7, hence the chance that it's possible with the non-existing itext 4 is close to zero.

Comment: If you're a contractor and you want to secure a nice assignment with this customer, please show them this link: [Can iText 2.1.7 / iTextSharp 4.1.6 or earlier be used commercially?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5) Tell your customer that maintenance also involves compliance and upgrading. You could propose a project to migrate to iText 7, and make sure that a commercial license is purchased (you could get a commission on the purchase price) so that the project is also OK from a legal point of view.