# iText 4.2.0 - com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: No message found for trailer.not.found

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to flatten PDF document which mostly has Digital Signatures in them. However, I am facing an exception with a particular PDF file. The PDFReader throws an exception :

```
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: No message found for trailer.not.found
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.rebuildXref(Unknown Source)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(Unknown Source)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Below is my code segment:

```
public static void newFlatten() {
    System.out.println("Started new flattening process :: " + new Date().getTime());
    PdfReader reader;
    boolean bRet = false;

    try {
        reader = new PdfReader(SRC); // Place where i am getting exception
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(DEST));
        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
        Set<String> fieldKeys = form.getFields().keySet();


        /*for (String fieldKey : fieldKeys) {
            form.setField(fieldKey, "X");
        }*/
        stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
         System.out.println("Stop new flattening process :: " + new Date().getTime());
         System.out.println("Destination FIle :: "  + DEST);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Yes you are right, this is not been used at Honeywell, in Honeywell we have official licenses. I am using this version for some personal research as this is the last available LGPL/MPL version of iText. For more refernce - https://github.com/ymasory/iText-4.2.0

Comment: After remarks on iText 4.2.0 have been made, that error should only be thrown for invalid PDFs. Thus, for analysis please share a PDF for which that error occurs.

Comment: If this code isn't used at Honeywell, can you please explain why you are using a version of iText with known legal and technical issues?

Comment: isn't this version supposed to be having LGPL/MPL ?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie , I am using this version because i was working on a old code which was already having this version and i am trying to extend some funtionality before moving on to the latest versions of itext. It would be great if you could clear this - whether this version is LGPL/MPL or not ?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I guess there are some risks associated with this version, I have found out a couple of your answers related to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892830/concatenate-tagged-pdf-files-using-the-older-version-itext-4-2-0?rq=1 , May it would be wise to move to latest version as those are also available under AGPL and as this is a personal project i can make the source code open. Thanks For the heads up and the Info.

Comment: That code should not be `com.itextpdf` but should be `com.github.ymasory`. Yuvi Masory had every right to take an LGPL/MPL version of iText and make any changes they want, but they do not have the right to claim that it is a product released by the company iText Software. At least Andreas Rosdal had the common decency to rename his fork to OpenPDF.

Comment: Did you just say a nice thing about AR? :-)

Comment: I heard/read it, too :-) @PrashantChaudhary Or you alternativly use openPDF https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF